# Why are some CSS rule-sets uneditable in Chrome Element panel?

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7jMG.png)

I found that a CSS rule-set is uneditable. Does anyone know what can possibily cause it?

Comment: Can you send an example website to test that?

Comment: These are rules created with CSSStyleSheet API, Chrome can't edit them, see https://crbug.com/889781